# Cannot attach to Appium with WebStorm debugger

Tags: node.js, debugging, remote-debugging, webstorm, appium

I have git-cloned Appium and I am trying to debug it using *JetBrains WebStorm*.

### Remote debugging

I set the environment to remote debug a node application and provided the following parameters:

```
Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 8877
```

So I first run Appium by issuing: `appium --port 8877`. After that I run the debugger. The problem is that the debugger always reports:

> Connecting to localhost:8877...

In spite of Appium running and actually executing a test, the debugger cannot attach to it.
What is the problem here?

Comment: For remote debugging your application should be running with the parameter --debug=<port for debugging> or --debug-brk=<port for debugging>. Did you pass it to appium?

Comment: Not really. I understand I am doing this wrong and probably your point is correct. Please post an answer that I can check later if it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For remote debugging your application should be running with the parameter `--debug=<port for debugging>` or `--debug-brk=<port for debugging>`. 
See also http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Running+and+debugging+Node.js+application#RunninganddebuggingNode.jsapplication-DebuggingNode.jsappthatrunsremotely